# Same computation order using postfix notation?

Tags: arithmetic, stacks

I'm trying to understand arithmetic using stacks. Specifically converting infix notation to postfix notation. My question is how you convert an expression like: **1 + (2 + 3) + (4 + 5)**
that computes in the exact order that the order of operations says.

**Meaning: 1 + (2 + 3) + (4 + 5) becomes
1 + 5 + (4 + 5) then
1 + 5 + 9 then
6 + 9**

If you do:

**Push 1, Push 2, Push 3, Add, Push 4, Push 5, Add**

Where Add pops the top two operands off the stack, adds them, and then pushes the sum back on the stack.

Alternative notation: 1 2 3 + 4 5 +

How do you add 1 + (sum of 2 and 3) next? If you do another Add then the sum of 2 and 3 will be added to sum of 4 and 5, because these are the top two on the stack. **Is it impossible to do it in the exact same order? Doing each parentheses group first left to right then doing the rest of the computation left to right.**

Comment: Push 1, Push 2, Push 3, Add, Add ?

Comment: Thanks for responding. But that is 1 + (2 + 3) right? You haven't done (4 + 5) before 1 + (2 + 3) like order of operations from left to right would dictate. I understand you can get the same final sum but I was curious if you can do the computation exactly the same in postfix as infix everytime.

Comment: I don't think it's possible without uses other instructions that affect the stack. The reason is that you're using "ternary plus". Try converting your original expression to incorporate only binary plus.

Comment: Sorry what is ternary plus? Again thanks for the response.

Comment: It's the function that takes $a,b,c$ to $a+b+c$. Binary plus takes $a,b$ to $a+b$.

Comment: In other words, you are requested to fully parenthesize your expression.

Comment: Oh, I thought I was trying to use binary plus. Push 1 onto stack then Add 2 to 3 to give 5 and push that on the stack., Then add 4 to 5 to give 9 and push 9 onto stack. Then how to add 9 on stack to the 1 on the stack?

Comment: If you fully parenthesize your expression, you won't be able to justify your weird evaluation order. That's the root of the problem.